# What is the difference between model.get_layer() and model.get_layer().output

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, transfer-learning

I know this is silly question but I am little bit confused here...
for I am using transfer learning using VGG16 and it has a layer named 'block4_pool'.
so what is the difference between the objects these two lines returns,

```
base_model.get_layer('block4_pool')
base_model.get_layer('block4_pool').output
```

what are they returning?

Comment: so if I have like X=tf.keras.layers.Dense(12, activation='relu')(Y) , then X is the output tensor of this dense layer and X is not the Dense layer object itself?

Comment: and this output tensor X can be passed to next layer.  am I correct?

Comment: Yes. ``X`` is a tensor that you pass to the next layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one returns a **layer object** which is a MaxPooling2D layer.

The second one is the output **tensor** of this layer.

let's see what is exactly these are:

First statement:

```
print(base_model.get_layer('block4_pool'))

>>  <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D object at 0x7f50fe7f8ed0>
```

Second statement:

```
print(base_model.get_layer('block4_pool').output) 

>>  KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 9, 9, 512), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='block4_pool/MaxPool:0', description="created by layer 'block4_pool'")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
base_model.get_layer('block4_pool')
```

Retrieves the layer named `block4_pool` which is a `tensorflow.keras.layers` object

```
base_model.get_layer('block4_pool').output
```

Retrieves the output tensor(s) of the layer named `block4_pool`.